# What is the operator for inverting the sign of the argument of a function?

Tags: symbolic

I want an operator that takes as input a function of a real variable e.g. `f(x)` and returns as output the answer `f(-x)`. How does one define such an operator in Mathematica?

Comment: `f[x] /. h_[a_]:>h[-a]`  but I guess the best solution may be background dependent. So what it the big picture here? What have you tried?

Comment: Try `f @* Minus`.

Comment: Thanks for all answers. I am looking for Pure functions only. Some of these will work for me...

Answer (score 6):

You can define such a operator like so.

```
yAxisReflect[f_] := (f[-#] &)
```

where `f` is a symbol naming a function or a pure function.

With this definition, you can do things like

```
Plot[{Sin[x], yAxisReflect[Sin][x]}, {x, -π, π}]
```

[image: sine]

```
Plot[{(1 + x)^2, yAxisReflect[(1 + #)^2 &][x]}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image: square]

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to define a "negative" function directly:

```
g[x_] := f[-x]
```

So however `f[x]` is defined, `g[x]` gives `f[-x]`. But really, why do this? Wouldn't it be simpler and clearer just to use `f[-x]` directly whenever needed?

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[reflectionF1, reflectionF2]
reflectionF1[f_] := Compose[f, Minus, #] &;
reflectionF2[f_] := Composition[f, Minus] (* f @* Minus  in V 10.0+ as suggested by JM *)
```

Using m_goldberg's example setup:

```
Row[{Plot[{Sin[x], reflectionF1[Sin][x]}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["reflectionF1", 16, "Panel"], ImageSize -> 400, PlotStyle -> Thick], 
  Plot[{Sin[x], reflectionF2[Sin][x]}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]},
   PlotLabel -> Style["reflectionF2", 16, "Panel"], ImageSize -> 400, PlotStyle -> Thick]}]
```

[image]